# Laravel LockTimeoutException equivalent in Golang

Tags: go, redis

I want the multiple requests of a same API for a specific users to be executed sequentially. If 3 requests of same API for a users comes together then the 1st request should be processed immediately and the 2nd and 3rd request should be put on wait. 2nd request should start execution only after the completion of 1st request. 3rd request should start execution only after the completion of 2nd request and so on.

For example, user making 3 scan and pay back to back

```
Request R1 POST create-txn/user001  {amount : 50}
Request R2 POST create-txn/user001  {amount : 100}
Request R3 POST create-txn/user001  {amount : 10}
```

In Laravel we handle like:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\LockTimeoutException;


function createTxn()
{
    $lock = Cache::lock("create_txn_" . $postdata['user_id'] . '_lock', 30);
    try {
        $lock->block(5); // Lock acquired after waiting maximum of 5 seconds..

        // code for creating txn
    } catch (LockTimeoutException $e) {
        throw new ServiceErrorException('create txn api LockTimeout Exception', 105);
    } finally {
        optional($lock)->release();
    }
}
```

I want the Go equivalent code for the above logic. I tried bsm/redislock and mutex but I did not get the expected result. Need example in Go.

Comment: The `Laravel LockTimeoutException`  will make the requests execute in queue style? Or just like the competitive lock? And you need the guarantee of execution order?

Comment: I'm not worried about execution order but 2 requests should not be processed at once. Next request should be executed only after the completion of the current request.

Comment: Could you please show me your code with bsm/redislock or mutex?

Comment: `
import (
.....
  "github.com/bsm/redislock"
  "github.com/redis/go-redis/v9"
   "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)
func getTestByID(c *gin.Context) {

    id := c.Param("id")
    lockKey := "test_"+id;
    fmt.Println("recieved", id, lockKey)
 // Connect to redis.
 client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
  Network: "tcp",
  Addr:  "127.0.0.1:6379"
 })
 defer client.Close() 
 locker := redislock.New(client)
 ctx := context.Background()
 lock, err := locker.Obtain(ctx, lockKey, 100*time.Millisecond, nil) 
 defer lock.Release(ctx)
 time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond)
} `

Comment: if I click url http://localhost:8080/test/4 multiple times, all executes immediately

Comment: Could you edit your question description, and paste your code there?

Comment: ```import (
  "github.com/bsm/redislock"
  "github.com/redis/go-redis/v9"
)

func main() {
router.GET("/test/:id", getTestByID)
func getTestByID(c *gin.Context) {
    lockKey := "test_"+c.Param("id");
    fmt.Println("recieved", id, lockKey)
 client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
  Network: "tcp",
  Addr:  "127.0.0.1:6379",
  DB:      9,
 })
 
 defer client.Close()
 locker := redislock.New(client)
 ctx := context.Background() 
 lock, err := locker.Obtain(ctx, lockKey, 100*time.Millisecond, nil)  
 defer lock.Release(ctx)
 time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond)
}```

Comment: Any idea why below code is not working `locker := redislock.New(client)
ctx := context.Background()
lock, _ := locker.Obtain(ctx, "my_key_"+id, 5*time.Second, nil) //not imposing a lock
defer lock.Release(ctx)
fmt.Println("I have a lock!")
time.Sleep(4*time.Second)
fmt.Println("5s")` When called http://localhost:8080/test/4 multiple times first print can be executed immediately for all the calls but 2nd and 3rd print statements should be delayed due to lock for the 2nd request onwards